# Biblaridion's equation for making a star based off its luminosity

Tags: stars, worldbuilding-resources

I have searched for at least 45 minutes and I can't seem to find it. If you don't know what I'm talking about, in Biblaridion's first Alien Biospheres Video, he mentioned the you could calculate a star based off its luminosity.

Comment: I've added an appropriate tag for you. By "calculate a star" do you mean it's mass, composition, age - that sort of thing? Perhaps you might [edit] to say. Any worldbuilding context (what you want the star to be like) might help in finding the right answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the planetary formation was a collaboration with Artifexian for his alien biosphere serie, is in his channel that you will find lots of worldbuilding tutorials on celestial mechanics and geology.

Answer (score 6):

### A Suggestion

I watched that video a few years ago and, as I recall, the star/world building was done by [Artifexian](https://www.youtube.com/user/Artifexian). I would recommend reviewing some of his (much shorter) videos if you're still getting the hand of this. That said, below are the basic star equations.

## Star Equations

For reasons that will be obvious shortly, it's generally easier to start with a stellar mass and derive the luminosity and other properties.

> **NOTES:**
>
> 1. In the equations below, any value with a subscript of "☉" (e.g., $M_☉$) is the relevant value for our sun while a subscript of "*" (e.g., $L_*$) will be the value for the created star.
> 2. The equations below all assume you're dealing with a [main sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_sequence) star. Results will almost certainly be wrong if you're doing some other type.
> 3. In general, all of these equations give approximations as the relationships are not exact.

**Luminosity**

In terms of solar luminosity ($L_☉$):
$$ L_* =
\begin{cases}
0.23M_*^{2.3},  & \text{if }M_* < 0.43M_☉ \\
M_*^4, & \text{if }0.43M_☉ < M_* < 2M_☉ \\
1.5M_*^{3.5}, & \text{if }M_* > 2M_☉
\end{cases}$$
If desired, we can convert this common units with simple multiplication:
$$ L_☉ = 3.828\times10^{26} w $$

**Radius**

In terms of solar radii ($R_☉$):
$$ R_* = M_*^{0.8} $$
Again, convert to common units with multiplication:
$$ R_☉ = 6.955\times10^{5} km $$

**Surface Temperature**

In terms of solar temperature ($T_☉$):
$$ T_* = \left({{L_*}\over{R_*}}\right)^{.25} $$
or, if you prefer:
$$ T_* = \sqrt[4]{{{L_*}\over{R_*}}} $$
Again, convert to common units with multiplication:
$$ R_☉ = 5778K $$
$$ R_☉ = 5504.84°C $$

With temperature you can [look up spectral class and determine approximate color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification).

**MASS**

As shown in the luminosity equations, the relationship between mass and luminosity is complex. A little playing with those equations will show you the break points are around $0.033L_☉$ and $16L_☉$. If you need to start from luminosity for some reason, you can either solve each equation for $M_*$ or you can start plugging in mass numbers until you get your luminosity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a calculator to get the stars mass from luminosity [like this one here](https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/sspickle/Mass+from+Luminosity), then use the mass to calculate everything else. Artifexian has a pretty good videos on making a planetary system, and he has all the calculations in the description.